# Phonegap and Jquery Ajax call not working on HTTPS with correct certificate

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using:

Phongap 2.2.0
Jquery-Mobile 1.2.0
Jquery 1.7.1

I have an ajax call from the phonegap app to a server with HTTPS, and a valid certificate.

Things I have done:

1) ajax call works well with HTTP.
2) verified that the certificate was valid (firefox and chrome says so)
3) I have external host * in the plist (if not it would not work with HTTP)

Do you know what the problem can be?

Thanks

Comment: The phone OS could have a restricted set of trusted Certificate Authorities. Which platform are you testing on? Who is your certificate supplier?

Comment: I am testing on iPhone and iPhone Simulator.  The certificate supplier is GoDaddy and its a good certificate.

Comment: See: [SSL problem on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1980734), [“Server certificate untrusted” error in iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1315761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a cache issue somewhere.
Basically it was caching the old HTTPS certificate on the device,  and the old certificate was invalid.
After cleaning everything now its working fine.

thanks for the comments.